# NUPI in PPI (Teradata)

Tags: indexing, teradata, partition, database-indexes

In teradata why Primary Index must be declared as "non-unique" on all partitioned tables unless the primary index column is also used to define the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason is that the insert only goes to the relevant partition.  The other partitions don't ever see the row, so they don't have a chance to look for the primary index value and return a uniqueness violation. When the primary index is part of the partition then the uniqueness check can be done because the other partitions won't contain the value of the primary index for the row being inserted.  The 1 partition check is all that is needed to guarantee uniqueness.